# Protractor - switching from non-angular to angular page: "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page"

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm using Protractor to test an app consisting of 3 components:

1. `OpenAM` non-angular login component,
2. Non-angular app component,
3. Angular app component.

First, I login using the OpenAM component. Before login steps, I include `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` because otherwise I get `Angular could not be found on the page` error which is perfectly reasonable.
Then I execute some steps in the non-angular app component, and they execute without errors, although I don't include `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` neither in the steps code nor in the conf file.

Then, using a link inside the non-angular app component, I navigate to the angular app component, which opens in a new browser tab and here all hell breaks loose. No elements on the page are found, even when using waits, sleeps, etc., so I tried to use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` but when I do so, I get

> Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both
>   angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined".

What's interesting is that when I navigate directly to the angular app component from the `OpenAM` login page I face no such problems and all steps execute just fine.

Here's the login spec:

```
 export class LoginPage {
  public async loginUsingCredentials(user, pass) {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
    await username.sendKeys(user);
    await password.sendKeys(pass);
    await signIn.click();
  }

}
```

It is executed as a BeforeAll hook.

Other test steps are rather irrelevant to be posted here.

The important thing is that if I go directly to the angular app component using `browser.get('example:8080/angularapp')` all steps are executed without errors. 
But if I go to the main app component first `browser.get('example:8080')` execute some steps there and then move to the angular component using link, I get errors as described above.

In both cases, test steps for the angular component are the same. Also in both cases I need to login first using `OpenAM`.

Comment: Add some test scripts to give better view on the problem

Comment: add browser.ignoreSynchronisation = true; in config file.